# C# combobox fill in order , populate data from an external XML

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two comboboxes say `A` and `B` in C# winforms.
By default the B will disabled. I am populating data items in to A from an external xml file.

Now, if the user selects the choice in A, B will be enabled and will be populated from another XML depending on choice in A. And most importantly I have to achieve all of this in **single function**.

How do I achieve this?

I can trigger selection changed event for B, but that needs one more function. is there any way around?

here is the snippet though:

```
    XmlDocument errors = new XmlDocument();
    errors.Load("../../ErrorFile.xml");
    XmlElement root = errors.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode categoryNode = root.FirstChild;
    XmlNodeList nodes = categoryNode.ChildNodes;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
         A.Items.Add(nodes[i].Name);
    string category = A.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Currently i am stuck here: after populating A, code execution continues to look for choice in A and throws a null exception as soon as B in enabled and it sees no choice selected in A. I need to pause the execution until user selects a choice from A.

Comment: Why trigger event on B? You need to trigger A event and in that event populate data for B. Add your current code please.

Comment: Why do you need to do in a single function?

Answer (score 0):

Use A's ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event to populate combo box B

Comment: that makes me add one more function

Comment: Why do you need to do in a single function?

Comment: lets just say code constraints..i am working on some live project and i was asked to do this in only one function. if i can really use another function, i would not have asked this question.

Comment: Use the same function as event handler for combo box A. Do the tasks you want depending on the sender

Comment: There's nothing tricky here. Everything is really simple if you are not a new in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Bind combo box one to relevant xml file. And use its selection change event to bind combo box two to other xml related to combo box ones selected value.

Comment: Again, i need to add one more function for that.

Comment: Yes, Its just one event handler method for handle the combo box one selection change event

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a file "In.xml":

```
<root>
  <a name="1">
    <b>b1</b>
    <b>b2</b>
    <b>b3</b>
  </a>
  <a name="2">
    <b>c1</b>
    <b>c2</b>
    <b>c3</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

and a `Form` with two comboboxes, then:

```
    XElement x;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        x = XElement.Load("In.xml");
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(
             x.Elements("a")
              .Select(a => a.Attribute("name").Value)
              .ToArray());
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(
                    x.Elements("a")
                     .First(a => a.Attribute("name")
                                  .Value
                                  .Equals(comboBox1.SelectedItem))
                     .Elements()
                     .Select(b => b.Value)
                     .ToArray());
            }
        });
    }
```